# Increase Sampling rate on time-series data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have accelerometer data with variable sampling rate. I am trying to increase it a constant sampling rate 50hz through interpolation.The problem with the timestamps is, it doesn't have milliseconds.
[image]

How do i do it without losing the data i already have?

Answer (score 1):

You can first set the index as your datetime column using `df.set_index('timestamp')` and use `df.resample()`. The directive you want to pass into the `resample` function is `L` for milliseconds, but you can read more [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases). The `resample` function also lets you choose a number of interpolation modes.

Comment: I tried this  df.resample('20ms', on='timestamp').
This only take first occurence's value and increases the sampling rate but all the rest of data for that particular second is lost. Its just populated as nan.

Comment: I see. That's tricky because to `pandas`, it just sees a bunch of values with the same timestamp and doesn't know what to do with it. Moreover, it doesn't even seem that there are always the same number of repeated timestamps. It seems you may have roll something manually; basically go second by second, assume all values for a given second are spaced out evenly for a second, and interpolate using the mean of neighbors or something.

Comment: Another possible way is to go through second by second and change the timestamps so that they are spaced evenly by for how many times a second value repeats, and _then_ use resample to fill everything else. This way `pandas` will still do most of the work.